# VideoJS: modifying margin in an element of progress bar

Tags: javascript, css, video.js

When we move mouse over the progress bar of videojs video vidjet we see a tip with a thumbnail image an small box with time (having `vjs-mouse-display` class). It's is described inside videojs lib. There we have e.g. something like the following

```
.video-js .vjs-progress-control .vjs-mouse-display {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 1; 
}
```

I need to set `margin-top` property of that box. In the scss (that is outside of lib) I'm trying to do

```
.video-js .vjs-progress-control .vjs-mouse-display {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

And that does not work. I was trying to use `.video-js .vjs-progress-control div.vjs-mouse-display` selector (that should have move priority than original one), even tried to put `important!` but that had no effect too.

Of cause if I can set `margin` with JS. But maybe there's a way to do this through CSS?

Comment: You just need to set it as `!important`..you can insert your style inside an `style` tag, like `<style>
.vjs-mouse-display {
    margin-top: 120px !important;
}
</style>`

Comment: Yes, that's definitely what I can do. But why it does not work in scss ?